# ShopifyQL raise error "Field 'shopifyqlQuery' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'"

Tags: python, graphql, shopify

I am trying to run a ShopifyQL query through Python, but I get the error "Field 'shopifyqlQuery' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'".

The reference used to build the query is found in: https://shopify.dev/api/shopifyql

Follow below the excerpt of the code used to get the query:

```
import json
import requests

API_KEY = MYKEY
PASSWORD = MYSECRET
SHOP_NAME = MYSHOP
API_VERSION = '2022-07'
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin/api/%s" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, SHOP_NAME, API_VERSION)

response = requests.post(shop_url+'/graphql.json', json={'query': GraphQLString})
answer = json.loads(response.text)
```

The full error follows:

```
{'errors': [{'message': "Field 'shopifyqlQuery' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'", 'locations': [{'line': 4, 'column': 3}], 'path': ['query', 'shopifyqlQuery'], 'extensions': {'code': 'undefinedField', 'typeName': 'QueryRoot', 'fieldName': 'shopifyqlQuery'}}]}
```

When I try to run other Shopify GraphQL queries the code works just fine, which makes me ponder that I maybe missing something simple in the query, but I can't figure out what's missing.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: figured out what's wrong. ShopifyQL does not use regular API version. Instead of using "2022-07", the version used in the example above, it is required to use "unstable" instead.